# iOS UIWebViewDelegates not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a `UIViewController` class named `WebScreenViewController`, which is having an `UIWebView`. Here is the class implementation file:

```
@implementation WebScreenViewController

@synthesize urlString;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self gotoUrl:self.urlString];
    //[self gotoUrl:@"http://www.google.com"];

}


#pragma mark - UIWebView Delegates
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    NSURL* url = [request URL];
    NSString* urlStr = url.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest. URLStr = %@", urlStr);

    return YES;
}
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");
}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString* html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body"];
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad: HTML string = %@", html);

}
-(void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailLoadWithError. ERROR: %@", error);
}

#pragma mark - Member Methods

-(void)gotoUrl:(NSString*)urlStr
{
    NSLog(@"Calling website %@ in UIWebView...", urlStr);
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

@end
```

The above code work well on one of my testing device but did not work on another. It worked on my iPod Touch with the latest iOS 8.1.2. But it didn't work on my iPad3 with iOS version 7.0. When I run it on my iPad3, it will call the `gotoUrl:` method and the log "Calling website %@ in UIWebView..." will be displayed. And that's it. I receive no more logs from the delegates. To check the internet connections, I tried using Safari on the same device and it was working.

Comment: did you check if self.webview is null in [gotoUrl:] ?

Comment: before setting the delegate first check whether it is initialised or not. If it is null then first initialise it then set its delegate.

Comment: Well, like I said, the above code works fine when I use it in my iPod. Meaning, all the NSLogs print out correctly. The problem is if I run it in my iPad, it won't work. So I don't know what's wrong with it that it couldn't work in a different device with a different OS.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you've connected the web view's outlet correctly in iPad storyboard if you're using different storyboards for iPhone & iPad.

Also check that the web view is not nil.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Like I said int he comment above, it actually worked on one of my devices but not in the other. So maybe it's not because of that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/"];
NSURL *loadURL=[NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSURLRequest *loadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:loadURL];
[webView loadRequest:loadRequest];
webView.delegate=self;
```

Try this way in your view did load or if you have URL you can replace first line like this

```
NSString * strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:self.urlString];
```